# Hangfire recurring job next execution time is empty

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, hangfire

This question may seem pretty dumb, so sorry about that. I'm new to Hangfire.

I'm using hangfire(with MongoDB) in my .net core app and things are good!

But yesterday I got the following errors for my recurring jobs using.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details. 
---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details. 
---> System.TypeLoadException: 
Could not load type 'AirQualityControl.Core.Models.Domain.AirMonitoringStation' from assembly 'AirQualityControl.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveType(Assembly assembly, String[] names, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)
enter code here
```

This is completely my fault ‍♀️ , 'cause I accidentally change the type namespace.
I revert those changes to previous state.

But I'm worried about current state of jobs:

[image]

As you might see the next execution is empty.

Usually it contains date and time when job will be triggered next time.

[image]

**So I guess that they will not be lunch according to CRON expression?**

**Do I need to somehow manually tweak these jobs?**

**Or they will run today at 7PM again according to CRON expression?**

Thank you so much for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: What is the configuration for max retry attempt in `hangfire` before the job is set to failed?

Comment: @NikhilPatil I'm not override this setting. So I believe it has a default value which  is 10, according to the source code.
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/AutomaticRetryAttribute.cs

Comment: I am not sure why next execution time is empty, because your job has failed only 5 times. From where are you fetching the next execution time? I cannot see any field in DB that stores this value. Do you have access to `hangfire` dashboard? Maybe you can check there?

Comment: @NikhilPatil I'v updated question with more details, to be more precise. Hope you will find it useful

Comment: Up. still have the same issue

Comment: @CherryBlossom, I've posted an answer that tries to describe an answer in details.
Hope you will find it useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: For those who are new to Hangfire and facing the same issue.**

Every job in Hangfire has a certain number of retries attempts. It might be a global setting or could be changed using the AutomaticRetry attribute per job.

By default every job has 10 retries attempt.

> If retry attempts exceeded their maximum, the job will be move to the
> Failed state (with an error log message), and you will be able to
> retry it manually.

Also, it's important to note that we might see hangfire with it's jobs as a finite-state machine.

[image]
*This image has an illustrational purpose only. This is not an accurate list of hangfire job's states*

That means that every job should have a certain state. Some of them are terminal and some of them are not.

[Here](https://api.hangfire.io/html/N_Hangfire_States.htm) you could find a complete list of hangfire's job states.

According to the documentation

> Failed - Defines the intermediate state of a background job when its
> processing was interrupted by an exception and it is a developer's
> responsibility to decide what to do with it next.

That means that **job would not be triggered automatically** and you should run it manually or get rid of it.